# AspectJ: how to return data from handler to method?

Tags: java, aspectj

I have a method:

```
@ApiLogRequest(httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST, path = "/planet")
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<PlanetDto> save(@RequestBody PlanetDto dto) {
    Long requestId;
    return ResponseEntity.ok(service.save(dto));
}
```

I have an annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ApiLogRequest {

    HttpMethod httpMethod();

    String path() default "";
}
```

I have an annotation handler that takes the data from request and saves it to the database.

```
@AfterReturning(value = "@annotation(after)", returning = "responseEntity")
public void after(ResponseEntity responseEntity, ApiLogResponse after) throws JsonProcessingException {
    service.save(ApiLog.of(
            TransferType.RESPONSE.name(),
            after.httpMethod().name(),
            after.path(),
            new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(responseEntity)
    ));
}
```

I want to send back the ID of the saved value to use it in the method further (in the case of `save()` method - `Long requestId`). Please tell me how to fix my handler so that I can return something from it back to the method and work with it.

Comment: Query: does anyone actually use AspectJ any more?  I thought it was dead and gone.

Comment: What can you recommend instead it?

Comment: I haven't done a lot of JEE, so my question is an actual question: for folks that do JEE, how much AOP is actually still used?  For you, just a modern JEE 3.0 using their CDI (injection framework) would likely be a better approach.

Comment: AspectJ is neither dead nor gone. In fact, there have been releases for Java 9, 10, 11 compatibility. It is still maintained by Andrew Clement who works for Springsource and so much more powerful than Spring AOP which only offers simple public method interception. But this is a meta discussion and does not solve the OP's problem, so I apologise to everyone for participating. I just wanted to contradict a statement I totally disagree with.

Comment: In an `@AfterReturning` advice you can react to a method having returned something. You cannot modify what gets returned, but if I understand you correctly this is what you want, right? So if you want to modify the return value, you need to use `@Around`. If I misunderstand you, please edit your question and explain. Otherwise please also expand and fix the sample code. E.g. you show annotation `@ApiLogRequest`, but the aspect uses `@ApiLogResponse`. And where does `service` come from? I would like to see the whole aspect, not just a snippet of it, in order to help you.